# How do I get manifold-ext to work in JBoss?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jboss, manifold

I'm trying to get the manifold java compiler plugin to work in JBoss. When I deploy I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: manifold.rt.api.IBootstrap from [Module "deployment.siterefresh_Web.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
```

The manifold project is here: http://manifold.systems/

My experience with this exception is that a JBoss module needs to be created. Do I need to do this? If so, how do I setup the custom module? I'm a bit confused about the directory structure of where the module needs to be placed.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add the manifold libraries to the build artifacts so they could be picked up by the runtime.